# How can generate 95%CI for GAM model in Stata?

Tags: confidence-interval, stata

I am analyzing a dataset with generalised additive models(GAM) in Stata. I want to obtain 95% confidence interval(95%CI) for my result. I have read the documentation in Stata ("Help gam") and discussed this problem with classmates, but know nothing. How can I extract 95%CI?

Thanks for any tips or discussions!

Good day!

---

After getting help from Michael M, I have calculated 95%CIs of Coef by using the formula (Coef +- 1.96 Std. Err). However, two of results are wrong (or I think they are wrong). Here are the results that I think are wrong:

1. With *P* of the Coef < 0.05, the Coef of variable 1 is 0.0010618 and the Std. Err is 0.0063311, so 95%CI of Coef is -0.011 to 0.013.
2. With *P* of the Coef < 0.05,the Coef of variable 2 is 0.0091901 and the Std. Err is 0.0065636, so 95%CI of Coef is -0.004 to 0.022.

The two 95%CIs cross 0 but with *P* < 0.05, so these results were wrong, weren't they?

Do these mean that the Coefs I analysed are unbelievable? I can't get right conclusions from results, right? (My classmates think I should reject the results I have analysed.)

Wish you good day! Eager to get your help!

Comment: Of what parameter?

Comment: My code is like this：xi: gam APRI LBXPFOA i.RIAGENDR  RIDAGEYR i.PIR i.education i.smoke i.drinkalcohol i.RIDRETH1 i.bmi if cohort1 ==1 [weight=weightPFAs], df(LBXPFOA:3).Its results include df, Lin. Coef，Std. Err ， z，Gain，P>Gain.It didn't appear 95%CI,but  I need  95%CI .What should I do?Thank you.

Comment: Sorry，I misunderstood your question. After discussing with classmates, I return to answer your question. The parameter is "Coef" (β) and I need to the 95%CI of Coef. Thank  you for help and attention.

Comment: I don't know STATA, but an approximate Wald CI would probably follow from calculating Coef +- 1.96 Std. Err. It would be good for someone with STATA knowledge to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The method you propose can be seen as an alternative. Anyway, we can obtain the 95%CI of Coef.